# Remove Double Quotes While Reading CSV Files in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

In VBA, I need to import a few R generated CSV files. However, the `split` function did not work properly and gave`Type mismatch`. My best guess is that: VBA added double quotes between each imported line. So the first line becomes `" 47.27284,  130.5583,  44.826609, 189.905367"`. I tried to remove double quotes using `replace` or `remove the first and last character` but the error still existed. Any suggestions to deal with this issue?

#### CSV file

```
  dose_BMD_r, dose_ED_r, dose_BMD_c,  dose_ED_c
  47.27284,  130.5583,  44.826609, 189.905367
  47.27284,  130.5583,  52.226171, 233.338840
  47.27284,  130.5583,   8.484266,   6.887616
```

#### VBA code

```
lin_ind = 1
Open text_fn For Input As #1                                    
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    If lin_ind = 1 Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        textline_1 = Split(textline, ",")
    End If
    lin_ind = lin_ind + 1
Loop
Close #1
```

Comment: How is `textline_1` declared?

Comment: I declare it as String.

Comment: Can you include your declarations? Did you verify your suspicion about the double quotes? I would be surprised if it added quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using `Dim textline As String, textline_1 As Variant` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Split` function returns array. So the variable where you store `Split`'s return value, should be array/variant.

Declare it as `Dim textline_1` that's it. It will work.

OR `Dim textline_1 () As String`